# WPF VB Move to Next Tab

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, tabs

In my XAML I have Tabs for 4 of them. I have msg box that shows up when the user clicks on tab 3 (Query Tab). The msg box "Did you load the query? " if user clicks yes I want it go to tab4 (DataMapTab). If they click no stay on the tab3.

Here is what I tried and am I failing...

```
 Select Case tabItemName
        Case "SecurityTab"
            Me.DataContext = New xFracasDataController.xDcViewModels.SecurityViewModel
        Case "QueryTab"
            Dim result As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Did you load the query", "caption", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
            If result = Forms.DialogResult.No Then
                MessageBox.Show("Cancel pressed")

            Else
                result = Forms.DialogResult.Yes
                Dim SelectedIndex As TabItem
                SelectedIndex = DataMapTab

            End If

            'MessageBox.Show("Did you load a Query ", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
            Me.DataContext = queryViewModel
        Case "ConfigureTab"
            Me.DataContext = configureViewModel
        Case "DataMapTab"
            Me.DataContext = dataMapViewModel

        Case Else
            'do nothing
    End Select

End Sub
```

Could some please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can switch the current tab by assigning one of the following properties:

- [`TabControl.SelectedItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem?view=netcore-3.1) - Your tab item instance
- [`TabControl.SelectedValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvalue?view=netcore-3.1) - Your selected value item
- [`TabControl.SelectedIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedindex?view=netcore-3.1) - The tab index as `int`
- [`TabItem.IsSelected`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.tabitem.isselected?view=netcore-3.1) - `bool` value on a `TabItem` itself

Which property to set depends on your actual implementation and requirements. From your code, I guess you want to use the `SelectedIndex` property, so the following examples will use it.

If you execute your message box code inside of an `ICommand` on a view model, you would expose a property for the `SelectedIndex` and bind it in XAML to the `TabControl`, then assign it in the bound command, but from your question I guess that is not what your are doing right now.

In a code-behind scenario, you could assign an `x:Name` to the `TabControl` like `tabControl` in this example and set the `SelectedIndex` directly, e.g.:

```
tabControl.SelectedIndex = 3
```

If you put your code in an event handler for the `SelectionChanged` event of the `TabControl`, you have to [defer execution of your `QueryTab` case code using the `Dispatcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invokeasync?view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_Threading_Dispatcher_InvokeAsync_System_Action_System_Windows_Threading_DispatcherPriority_), otherwise you the selection change will be broken. For more information on this, please refer to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7786300/wpf-selectedindex-set-issue-of-tabcontrol)

```
Case "QueryTab"

   Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(
      Sub()
         Dim result = MessageBox.Show("Did you load the query", "caption", MessageBoxButton.YesNo)

         If result Is MessageBoxResult.No Then
            MessageBox.Show("Cancel pressed")
         Else
            tabControl.SelectedIndex = 3
         End If
      End Sub, DispatcherPriority.Render)

   Me.DataContext = queryViewModel
```

Answer (score 0):

Does that work for you?

```
Select Case tabItemName
        Case "SecurityTab"
            Me.DataContext = New xFracasDataController.xDcViewModels.SecurityViewModel
        Case "QueryTab"
            Dim result As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Did you load the query", "caption", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
            If result = Forms.DialogResult.No Then
                MessageBox.Show("Cancel pressed")

            Else
                result = Forms.DialogResult.Yes
                Dim SelectedIndex As TabItem
                TabControl1.SelectedTab = TabControl1.TabPages(“Tabname”)
                ‘ or TabControl1.SelectedTab = TabControl1.TabPages(4)


            End If

            'MessageBox.Show("Did you load a Query ", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
            Me.DataContext = queryViewModel
        Case "ConfigureTab"
            Me.DataContext = configureViewModel
        Case "DataMapTab"
            Me.DataContext = dataMapViewModel

        Case Else
            'do nothing
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Note: this was tested only on Windows forms not WPF, so I’m not sure it will work. You’ll have to replace TabControl1 with the name of your tabcontrol.